# how to get nearby flickr photos android

Tags: android, flickr

I am using [FlickrjApi4Android](http://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/) to get the nearby public photos based on user location. I have tried

```
Flickr.getGeoInterface().photosForLocation(...)  
//and
Flickr.getPhotosInterface().search(...).
```

I am providing longitude, latitude and accuracy/radius in both methods, but none of these returning any result. Any idea?

Comment: Have you solved this ?? I also have the same problem ....